# Is there a way to programatically determine the memory usage of an app in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am developing the iOS side of a Xamarin app and I need to programatically ask about memory availability.
In UWP, I am calling the `Windows.System.MemoryManager`.

Is there an iOS equivallent?

Comment: please search before posting.  This has been asked numerous times

Comment: Thank you @Jason and sorry for wasting your time. Unfortunately I had been searching for some time, and this did not come up. Maybe Google didn't want to do me a favor :)